# White Screen in phonegap app after downloading from Google Play

Tags: android, cordova

I developed a phonegap application (version 2.1.0) which is running fine on my Android emulator and device (when I physically copy APK from computer to device). But if I upload this APK to google play and then install on my same device it shows me a white screen and in some phones its getting error "https://example.com webpage is not available" .

Here is the use case -

```
<a href="https://example.com" rel="external" data-role="button">Connect</a>
```

This opens screen on emulator, device but shows white screen when I download from Google Play.

My PhoneGap config.xml has

```
<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->
<access origin="https://example.com" subdomain="true" />
<access origin="http://example1.com" subdomains="true" /> 
<access origin=".*"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using either

```
<access origin="https://example.com" />
```

or just

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Also remember that this must be a domain, you cannot connect to an IP address from a phonegap app.

Comment: Hi pppontusw , thanks for your reply. I have already added above lines. As I said its working in Emulator. Its also working in my device if I physically copy APK to my device or run device as emulator. Its not working when I download same APK from google playstore.

Comment: Have you made sure that the APK in the Play Store is the correct version, with the right Android version number? Can you download it from Play Store and run adb logcat to debug from your computer?

Comment: I checked that and both the APK are same (version no etc). Here is the new thing while I did adb logcat of my APK (downloaded from playstore) I found following problem - D/CordovaWebView( 2668): >>> loadUrlNow()
D/CordovaLog( 2668): JSCallback Error: Request failed with status 0  When I uninstalled that APK and run same APK from my ecliplse that error was not there

Comment: Seems very weird, you would indeed get a "status 0" if the domain is not whitelisted properly. I can't really figure out what is wrong, maybe you have already tried but otherwise can you increment the version number and upload your new package to the Play Store? If it would be any help I can test if it works on one of my Android devices, if you want to share the link?

Comment: I upgraded cordova to version 2.4.0 but no luck ! But the logs are-`D/CordovaWebView(18866): >>> loadUrl(https://example.com/)
D/CordovaWebView(18866): >>> loadUrlNow()
D/DroidGap(18866): onMessage(onPageStarted,https://example.com)
V/AudioFlinger( 1323): getNextBuffer() no more data for track 4102 on thread 0x6
3328
V/AudioFlinger( 1323): stop(4102), calling thread 1513
V/AudioFlinger( 1323): (> STOPPED) => STOPPED (4102) on thread 0x63328`

Comment: I got a major breakthrough when I changed URL from https:// to http it worked !! My app has to run on https. Adding https in config.xml did not help. I think Google is adding some SSL check.